# ios application crashes when taking a screenshot due to memory spike

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, screenshot

I have an app with multiple view controllers and navigation controllers. If I switch between two view controllers about 10 times and then take a screenshot from my iphone the application freezes, the memory spikes up to 1 GB and then crushes. If I take the screenshot after 4-5 switching between screens the app does not crash when taking screenshot. I suspect my app is creating multiple instances of the view controllers and I did not find a way to release them.
Anyway if you could give me any tip it will much appreciated. In my example I present the two view controllers like this:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "comanda")
let first = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

and

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "meniuControl4") as! SideMenuController
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Are you using dismissViewController to go back? Or you are just presenting the controller everytime you want to go to that screen?

Comment: I am not using dismiss to go back, I could try that although I saw some table cells remain selected and messes some other states but I can try to fix that.

Comment: You can do cell.selectionStyle = .none , so that they dont highlight. You can do it in cellForRowAt method or from storyboard

Comment: You need to post more of the code around how this is used. If this is all you have, then you keep adding the same screens to the stack over and over, which will cause massive issues. Also your first code sample declares 2 viewControllers and only uses 1

Comment: Main Controller is being presented from a side menu controller. When I go back I dismiss the current controller and land on the existing instance of the main one but when I get back using the menu I create a new instance, even if i use a segue. The problem is I have many controllers tied to this menu controller which do not have a back button but instead are using the sliding menu. I cannot change the design flow unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling the above code from within each of the two view controllers, then you're never dismissing either one, you just keep presenting one on top of another which is adding to memory.

I don't know what the flow of your app is, but if you present a view controller using `present(_:animated:completion:)` then you should call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` at some stage from within that view controller to navigate backwards. If you call `present(_:animated:completion:)` from within it to get to another view controller and keep doing this, then you just keep adding view controllers on top of each other like a deck of cards.

Comment: As Mr.P said you're continuously device memory by presenting VCs without dismissal. It would helpful to understand next things: 1 - how do you identify a spike 2 - do your vc contain any business logic, additional UI elements, data? It is quite strange that 10 vc can load device memory 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, i have added a dismiss on the back navigation but main controller still gets loaded I can't find a way to dismiss previous instances. The application runs ok and does not take too much memory although it continues to add when I go back to the main controller which is also loading data from memory. It only crashes if I call many VCs and then take a screenshot from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for all the help. I managed to fix the problem using dismiss when going back one step and **unwind segues** when returning to the main screen. Now the app does not crashes when I take a screenshot no matter how many VCs I go through and come back.